# What to use for this floor transition?

Tags: flooring

Recently bought a house with some questionable finishes. Just wondering what I would use here to transition between the tile and laminate flooring?

I am guessing I cannot use a T-moulding, as the notch will not fit. Thus, do the make something that is used for these particular situations? From the videos I have seen online, the gap is normally much larger than shown in my picture.

I was thinking of something like an [oak carpet strip](https://www.lowes.ca/floor-trim/m-d-building-products-36-in-x-1-7-16-in-unfinished-oak-carpet-trim_10363376.html?af=3632&cse=3632&gclid=COHBlpjK1tICFYJmfgodSYEFcA&gclsrc=aw.ds), as I can stain it. But it has screw holes, and I would prefer to glue something down? Again, I have zero experience here.
[image: Floor gap]

Comment: Are the two surfaces equal height?

Comment: Is the margin between the two surfaces consistent all the way as shown in the picture?

Comment: The height may be off by 1/16 or less. The spacing is not equal from one end to the other. Thus, the transition pieces with a notch will not work (as far as I know). Total region is about three feet long.

Comment: Usually people whom setup that narrow of a clean edge between tile and wood intend to buy a tube of polyurethane grout to fill the crack with. They wouldn't use normal grout as it wouldn't handle the movement needs between the materials. Maybe they just didn't have any on hand when grouting the tile.

Comment: Can you/you can- cut the laminent enough to make a gap wide enough for the track of t moulding ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use T-moulding, you can cut the laminate back to make room. Probably the best tool would be an oscillating mulitool. You can get these with different types of blades, but the key thing is they can do fairly accurate plunge cuts to a controlled depth, and they can cut right in a corner/against a wall with almost no clearance.

[image: Oscillating multitool with straight blade]
[image: Oscillating multitool with round blade]

Comment: This is the right fix. Even a circular saw will do the job well enough, given the substantial lap that a T-molding provides.

Comment: Only trouble with a circular saw is getting to the edge (against a wall/door frame), but a small hand saw can work for that (though it may take a while).